# catch SWIG extension stdout in python

Tags: python, stdout, swig

I'm integrating a 3rd party C++ library to a python application using SWIG. The 3rd party library outputs important information to stdout. I would like to catch that output in python. The package is precompiled and I don't have access to its code, only to an API header file, therefore I cannot change the output stream in any way.

How can I capture the SWIG extension's stdout in python?

Comment: Just to confirm: You want to capture stdout from the code you're wrapping and then pass that back to python? What way do you want to expose it to Python? Would redirecting it to a temporary file be ok? (That's probably simplest, but there are smarter things that could be done, e.g. call some Python, in another thread on every write to stdout would be possible also).